# is in_forward plugin of fluentd async?

Tags: php, fluentd

I'm currently doing some research on async event logging projects. In the documentation of fluentd, I've seen the built-in `in_forward` plugin. I'm trying to use it with php event logger of fluentd. I'm trying to forward the local logs into a central log server with use of different plugins of fluentd. For example, I've used cassandra-cql plugin to save the event logs on cassandra column family.

So, here's my question;

Exactly when do I get response from when using `forward` ?

Is it after a successful write on local td-agent's ? 
Is it after a successful cassandra write ?
Is it completely async ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using PHP client, the client library just sends a log record to local Fluentd and doesn't receive any ack message etc from the local agent. Meaning it's completely async.

- http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/php